# Disabling a button in C# WITHOUT setting btn.Enabled = false;?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

Is there any other way beside the `button1.Enabled = false;` to disable the user from clicking it?

I'm implementing simple TicTacToe game in WinForms and if I use the Enabled property the colors of the button's text is turning into gray which is ruining my user interface a lot.

I would like to keep my formatting for the button and just disable further clicking from the user.

Comment: Your click method could conditionally decide to do nothing when clicked.

Comment: Adding the essential part of your code behind might help.

Comment: Do you want to really prevent any clicking visual, or just avoid any interaction once the user click? If it's the second, you can easily put a boolean and just return immediately if you need.

Comment: The click event belongs to the Control class. Every control has a click event. For example a PictureBox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The probably simplest way is to detach the event handler once it is called.

```
void HandleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Button)sender).Click -= HandleClick;

    // Handle the click  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this really was the most simple solution among the others.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep an array of booleans for all of your buttons example

```
bool [] buttonClicked = new bool [9];
```

then you have 9 button click event handlers

```
private void button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArg e)
{
    if(buttonClicked[0]==true)
      return;
    else
    {
        // your code goes here
        // mark this button in boolean array as clicked
        buttonClicked[0] = true;
    }
}
```

and dont forget in every new game to reset the buttonClicked array values to false

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    buttonClicked[i]=false;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In each square you could place a label and a button. When the button is pressed it hides itself (setting Visible to false) and shows the label (again by setting its Visible property). The labels text can be set to either O or X.